# Automatically reject incoming call when already on the phone with someone in Microsoft Teams

Tags: windows, office365, microsoft-teams

Is there a setting in Microsoft teams that would automatically end an incoming call, when you are already in a call?

Example:

- UserA calls UserB
- During their call UserC calls UserB
- Right now UserB has to manually reject UserC's incoming call
- What I want to achieve is that UserC's incoming call is terminated immediately, because UserB is already on the phone with UserA

Is there a way to do this? I have Full Access to Teams Admin Center, Office 365 Admin Center and all PowerShell Cmdlets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Calling policies in Microsoft Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-calling-policy), you need to create a new policy or edit your current policy, and configure the [Busy on Busy is available while in a call](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-calling-policy#busy-on-busy-is-available-while-in-a-call:%7E:text=Busy%20on%20Busy%20is%20available%20while,This%20setting%20is%20disabled%20by%20default.) setting:

> Busy on Busy (Busy Options) is a new setting that lets you configure how incoming calls are handled when a user is already in a call or conference or has a call placed on hold. New or incoming calls can be rejected with a busy signal. You can enable busy options at the tenant level or at the user level. Regardless of how their busy options are configured, users in a call or conference or those with a call on hold are not prevented from initiating new calls or conferences. This setting is disabled by default.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: yes that was it. thanks a lot. it's worth mentioning that there is a user voice that wants this as a setting on user level: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/39696967-automatically-block-incoming-calls-when-you-are-al